# For ARM, why is a single STM instruction generally faster than multiple STR instructions?

Tags: performance, assembly, arm, cpu-architecture

Is it related to some prefetch technology?
Or with [DDR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDR_SDRAM) access timing characteristics?

Answer (score 7):

If I remember correctly, starting with ARMv5TE, the path to the write buffer and the [L1 caches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache#Multi-level_caches) is 64 bit wide to accommodate the LDRD/STRD instructions. This allows STM to write two registers per cycle.

You'll also save a bit of L1 instruction-cache and use only one pipeline on dual-issue cores, which is also an additional gain.

Answer (score 4):

More instructions, more fetch cycles, and more instructions to execute, takes longer.

The busses are or can be 64 bits wide. For a single register stm, there isn't any gain, but with more than one register there can be a reduction both in the number of bus cycles to move the data, and depending on the memory system, if 64 bits wide, you don’t have a read-modify-write which is slow as well.

If it has to read-modify-write into the cache, where it normally would have been a write through, you lose cache space, as well as the cost of the read.  Even if it is a hit in cache, the read-modify write might cost you.

You can go to ARM's site and download the amba/axi specification and see how the bus transactions work. There are a number of clock cycles involved for every transaction (multiple transactions can be in flight at once, yes). Once you get past the overhead, it is a clock per 64 bits worth of data, so 128 bits takes one more clock than 64 bits to transfer. 32 bits and 64 bits take the same amount of clocks to transfer (if aligned).

I can’t speak for all architectures, but I believe on at least one I saw that only reads would actually do more than 64 bits per transfer.  Writes were broken into separate 64 bit transfers.  I could be remembering that wrong.

If you move four words worth of data, read or write, unaligned, I believe that becomes four separate transfers, one for each of the odd words and one for the aligned 64 bits in the middle.  So alignment can matter.

Comment: I don't think that this is related to AXI/AMBA. Usually the store will first hit the writebuffer which is part of the core and does not connect to the internal busses.

Comment: The core has the l1 cache and the interface is not amba/axi, sure, but if there is a miss then it goes to the l2 cache which is on an amba/axi, then if a miss it goes out on another amba/axi bus.  Either way more instructions means more individual transactions, each transaction has overhead.  I forgot to add in the mmu if there is one (often has one if there is a cache) which further adds to the overhead cost per transaction.

Comment: @dwelch: For the MMU, there will only be a (maybe two) TLB hit/misses.  It will be the same in both cases (for the data).  Unless you are talking about code; there is more to look up with multiple `STR` fetches plus the multiple `STR` fill the code cache reducing it's efficiency.

Comment: if it misses the tlb it has to go to ram which can miss the l1 and miss the l2 and go to ram, it can be at a minimum one or two extra clocks, to many clocks, either way it is a measurable, noticeable, difference between multiple strs and one stm.

Comment: Yes, but you are talking about code exclusively.  Is that correct?  The data is the same no matter what.  Or I don't understand.  The data will be in the same pages so that TLB look-up will be the same no matter where it is done?

Comment: the entire question has to do with the number of separate memory transactions between multiple str instructions vs a single stm instruction.  and trying to explain why stm CAN (not always) have an advantage over multiple strs.  multiple transactions is multiple tlb lookups vs a single transaction and a single lookup (yes you have the problem of crossing a page boundary).  the first tlb lookup has the same price, if there are more transactions then the price adds up.  same goes for the internal and external busses, core and cache.

Answer (score 2):

When is that true?

According to [this handy table](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0091a/BEIEDGJJ.html), the `STM` instruction takes 2 cycles to store a single register, or *n* cycles to store *n* registers for *n* > 1.

On the other hand, `STR` always takes 1 single cycle.

When do you get that `STM` is faster than `STR`?

- For one register, `STM` is slower.
- For *n* registers (*n* > 1), they're the same.

On the other hand, the above reference is for the ARM9TDMI architecture, and there are many ARMs.

Comment: +1 for chart, -1 as I don't think you have read the chart properly.  The data bus is as you say.  STR[1N] vs STM[1N + (n-1)S] with *big assumption* the memory bus is zero/symmetric wait states.  For the I-channel it is STR[1S] vs STM[1S+(n-1)I].  The 'I' means that if the next instruction is not dependent on the registers, they can run *immediately*.  Even for the ARM9TDMI, there is a difference.

Comment: In a recent practice, I found when L1 cache and MMU disabled, memset (implemented with STM) is much faster than a for loop value assignment. @unwind