# the speed of arm assembly ldm and ldr

Tags: assembly, arm

I'm writing an arm assembly code, and I want to load two 32bit data to registers, there are two instructions I can use,

```
1.   ldm             r0, {r1, r2}    
2.   ldr             r1, [r0]!
     ldr             r2, [r0]
```

I'd like to know **which one is faster**?

Comment: Just do a loop of 1e9 loads and compare. But it will also depend on memory (caches), etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [For ARM, why a single STM instruction is generally faster than multiple STR instructions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15500308/for-arm-why-a-single-stm-instruction-is-generally-faster-than-multiple-str-inst)

Comment: All the information in `STM` vs `STR` is the same as `LDM` versur `LDR`.  Mainly, you have done the same code in one less instruction.  The `ldrd` is more flexible to address memory, but has registers limitation.  You can use r0,r1 or r2,r3, etc.  You can not use r1,r2 for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instruction cycle timing slightly varies depending on the architecture.

ldm is theoretically faster when loading two or more registers, just counting the cycle numbers. But does it matter? Hardly, since most cycles are wasted due to the cache miss penalties. Aligning the addresses according the cache line is vastly more important.

It's not the performance, but probably the reduced code size that's beneficial.

Summing it up, try to utilize ldm/stm when they don't cripple your algorithm/implementation.

If you want to access memory ASAP no matter the cost, ldrd/strd are the best candidates.

What's the "cost"? A memory alignment of eight PLUS two consecutive registers.

It's your call.

PS : ldm/stm-like instructions are deprecated on the Aarch64 - for good reasons, and ldrd/strd equivalent ones are free of the "cost" mentioned above.

PS2 : There are some errors in your question

```
1.   ldm             r0, {r1, r2}    
2.   ldr             r1, [r0]
     ldr             r2, [r0, #4]
```